# How to manage Mock<Imediator> to work as normal IMediator using MSTest

Tags: .net, moq, mstest, mediator, mediatr

I am using Mock to establish the mediator variable in the controller via the test method.
But when the program encounters the mediator variable referring to mock the test case fails and as well no output is returned.

> await _mediator.Send(new Repository_function_called)

the repository function is called and all the variables are initialized. But when the mediator.Send() function is to work, the handler doesn't register to call the Handle method in the repository class.

What is the best possible alternative?

The Test class has this line for calling the controller method.

> var result =  await controller.Method_Name_in_Controller();

Comment: Are you trying to mock the behavior of MediatR for a unit test or are you performing an integration test? If you want MediatR to actually perform its intended purpose and you're not defining the mock behavior explicitly, it's no longer a mock...

Comment: To initialize the IMediator interface, I was looking at options and found Mock to be useful, so, when I initialize the Controller constructor with mock<IMediator>.Object, the handler part of the repository code seems to not work.

Comment: A mock instance is just that: a mock/fake. If you are expecting an IMediator instance to actually perform transferring a sent command to its corresponding handler, you have to use a real implementation along with its corresponding setup infrastructure.

Comment: Could you share an example,, of how to initialize the interface in test class and pass it to the controller method?

Comment: Adam, 
I have found the solution to the issue!
Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> var mediator = new Mediator(Mock.Of());

This method would not make a Moq value, and would be helpful!